# How do I access variadic template parameters in a way that is constexpr compatible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, compile-time

Item is a templated class that is initialized with an unknown number of templates of Init.

*I need to access the initialization data in some way at compile time. How it's done (templates, constexpr... whatever) doesn't matter.*

I can come up with tons of ways to store the data that is passed in, but I can't find any that allow the compile time access later.

Here's an example of what I would like to do. Ideally, variadic() would know about the class parameter pack, and be able to access it. That doesn't seem to be the case.

One more thing to note. I don't need the values of the parameters being passed in - the types would be enough, as I can access the data I need if I can get at least the types.

Any help would be appreciated!

header:

```
template <size_t Size, size_t Count> class Init
{
public:
    static constexpr size_t size()                  { return Size; }
    static constexpr size_t count()                 { return Count; }
};

template<typename ...Args> class A
{
public:
    A(){}

    template <size_t pos> constexpr size_t getSize()
    {
        return variadic<pos>().size();
    }

    template <size_t pos> constexpr auto& variadic(Args&&... args)
    {
        return variadicFind<pos>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    template <size_t Index, typename T, typename ...A> constexpr auto& variadicFind(T &&t, A&&... a)
    {
        return Index == 0 ? t : variadicFind<Index - 1>(std::forward<A>(a)...);
    }
};
using Item = A<Init<100, 100>, Init<50, 50>>;
```

cpp file:

```
Item i;
i.getSize<1>();
```

Comment: @Yakk - I need to access the initialization data in some way at compile time.

Comment: I need getSize<index>() to return compile time access to the data. There would be a similar function for the count, and some others for indexing.

Comment: With this example, i.getSize<0> should return 100, and i.getSize<1> should return 50. I don't care how the compile time access is done... templates, constexpr, tuples. Just need something that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metaprogramming boilerplate.  `types` bundles variardic args.  `nth_type` extracts the nth type from a bundle.

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
template<unsigned N, class types>struct nth_type;
template<template<class...>class types, unsigned N, class T0, class...Ts>
struct nth_type<N, types<T0,Ts...>>:
  nth_type<N-1, types<Ts...>>
{};
template<template<class...>class types, class T0, class... Ts>
struct nth_type<0, types<T0, Ts...>> {
  using type=T0;
};
template<unsigned N, class types>
using nth_type_t=typename nth_type<N,types>::type;
```

Traits to extract what you want from `Init`.  If you have more types that you want to pass to your `A` specialize `get_*` some more:

```
template <size_t Size, size_t Count> class Init {};

template<class>struct get_size;
template<size_t S,size_t C>
struct get_size<Init<S,C>>:std::integral_constant<size_t,S>{};
template<class>struct get_count;
template<size_t S,size_t C>
struct get_count<Init<S,C>>:std::integral_constant<size_t,C>{};
```

and done:

```
template<typename ...Args> class A {
public:
  A(){}

  template <size_t pos> constexpr size_t getSize() {
    return get_size<nth_type_t<pos, types<Args...>>>::value;
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you! Much appreciated. I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now. Tried so many things, but couldn't find a solution. Finally, I gave in and decided to ask :) I'll put this in my production code tomorrow and give the check mark when I verify this is right.